# How to avoid duplicate columns when doing left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Each has number of columns. But both has two columns in common.(ie: SiteCode,companyId)

I try to do left join for both common columns to create a view.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwAlarmActionSummaryYFUserSite]
AS
SELECT  *
FROM        [dbo].[vwAlarmActionSummary] alarmaction
LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[vwYfUserToSiteMappings] usersite on alarmaction.SiteCode = usersite.SiteCode 
and alarmaction.CompanyId = usersite.CompanyId
```

But Im getting

```
Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'SiteCode'on 'vwAlarmActionSummaryYFUserSite' is specified more than once.
```

How can I avoid this?
My requirement is get all columns from those two tables based on the above two conditions

Comment: You'll have to explicitly identify the columns you want to display.  Instead of `SELECT * FROM...` use `SELECT alarmaction.SiteCode, usersite.CompanyId,... FROM... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't select `*`. Pick your column names.

Comment: what's the best practice if the two table have a large number of columns? list them all?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, if you need them all. But even better to be deliberate about taking specific columns vs just assuming you want everything.

Answer (score 2):

It is very bad practice to use * in definitions view generally. There is no way to specifically exclude a column from one of the joined tables. However, you can use * (all columns) for one table, while providing explicit column names for the other, as below:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwAlarmActionSummaryYFUserSite]
AS
SELECT  
    alarmaction.[column name],
    ...
    usersite.*
    FROM        [dbo].[vwAlarmActionSummary] alarmaction
    LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[vwYfUserToSiteMappings] usersite on 
    alarmaction.SiteCode = usersite.SiteCode 
    and alarmaction.CompanyId = usersite.CompanyId
```

Best practice is still to explicitly list all columns from both tables, and include 'SiteCode' only once.

Comment: You said using `*` is bad practice and then you used it in your answer.

Comment: I try to provide a solution that's as close to what the op wanted as possible. Declaring something as good or bad practice is still a matter of opinion, so I'm just alerting the OP but leaving the choice up to them.